# Grew To Involve

Tags: catenative-verbs

I have a question about the abstract pattern "[verb1] to [verb2]" [here](http://www.thonline.com/news/national_world/article_21df8f44-2204-5705-bee3-1bb905aa5a78.html):

> The slaying of Hugo Pinell, 71, triggered a riot Wednesday that ***grew to involve*** about 70 inmates at a maximum security prison east of Sacramento, said California Department of Corrections and Rehabilitation spokeswoman Dana Simas.

I am confused about "*grew to involve about 70 inmates*".  Take another example:

> He jumped to look over the fence.

In the second example, the act of jumping was done to perform the looking over the fence.  So, according to abstract pattern "*[verb1] to [verb2]*", [verb1] was done to do [verb2].

But in the first example "*riot that grew to involve 70 inmates*", the fire growing ([verb1]) was not done to do the involving ([verb2]). It is more like, *[verb1]* happened, then *[verb2]* followed.

It seems that the "*[verb1] to [verb2]" pattern has two different interpretations.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks about right...

In *verb* "to" *verb*, sometimes a simple "**in order**" is missing.  So, "jumped to look" is really "jumped *in order* to look".

Now, about "grew to involve"... It looks of the same pattern as "swells to cover" or "shows to contain".  There is no preconceived *purpose* in the growing (or swelling, or showing), so we can't say that the 'in order' is missing here.  Then what is it?  It's an infinitive in the role of a noun or an adverb.  "Grew to involve about 70..." -- "grew [how much?] to involve about 70..."